# How to check if a redirect leads to a different domain

Tags: python, url, redirect, web, dns

I have a huge number of urls or domains and I want to determine whether they perform a redirect to a different domain.

When I check for status code 302, I can figure out which ones do a redirect. However, some of them just perform a redirect from `somedomain.com` to `somedomain.com/somename.php`, whereas the ones I need are those that do a redirect from `somedomain.com` to `otherdomain.com`.

I'm working with Python and the requests library and I have a somewhat limited knowledge when it comes to programming languages. If you have an idea that specifically requires me to use a different language, I suppose I can figure it out.

Comment: You mean you want to detect redirects to different domains? If so, then parse both URLs (see [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)) and check whether their domain differs.

Comment: If HTTP 200 is returned and the page redirects in a browser then http-equiv="refresh" or JavaScript is being used within the page.  You would need to parse out the former and use a headless browser for the latter. (This is unrelated to DNS)

Comment: @jweyrich so the idea is to parse the URL I enter, and the URL I get redirected to, and check if the redirection leads to a different domain?

Comment: @AlexK. HTTP 302 is returned, not 200.

Comment: @user2980055 assuming you want to detect whether the redirect is to a different domain than the one you've originally navigated, then yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `python-requests`, you can use `request.history` to get all redirections, except the final hop, which in turn will be available in `request.url`. For example:

```
r = requests.get("http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=99104")
for h in r.history:
    print h.url
print r.url

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=99104
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA100319991033.aspx
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HA100319991?CorrelationId=f32d077d-1c5b-4d12-ba24-8c500f36c5d1
```

If there is no redirection, then `request.history` will be an empty list.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

For example:
The following URL `http://mkc.mk` leads to `http://mkc.mk/?lang=en`. This counts as a redirect and using your code doesn't return an empty list. However, the actual domain of the website would still be `http://mkc.mk`. 
I'm trying to determine if the redirect leads to a different domain

Comment: My code only list all redirections. You would need to check for domain by yourself.